# grep + how to ignore many cases of marked ,lines

Tags: linux, bash, grep, solaris

I need to capture the **machine_VIP** (exactly match ) from **/etc/hosts** file

the problem is that in hosts file there are some lines with machine_VIP but they remarked before the machine_VIP or the line is remarked

so in this case we need to ignore the those lines

meenwhile I write the following command in order to get the IP that exists in the line with machine_VIP but it doesn’t took the right IP because the remarked character #

```
 Cluster_VIP=` grep -iw machine_VIP /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}' | head -1  `
```

example: ( of my hosts file )

```
  5.5.5.5  GH_T  T1 T2 T3 # machine_VIP
  # 198.2.3.12 MON1 MON2  machine_VIP
  18.2.4.12 W1 # machine_VIP # machine_VIP # machine_VIP
  192.9.200.77 machine_linux1 machine_linux2  machine_VIP
  192.9.200.78 machine_linux10 machine_linux20 machine_VIP_test
```

please advice what I need to add in my command in order to get the right matched IP

according to the example below the expected results should be:

```
 echo $Cluster_VIP

 192.9.200.77
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -w '^[^#]* machine_VIP' /etc/hosts | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

This searches for a line which has `machine_VIP` with no `#` before it.

Comment: shuld be support linux and solaris , did you think it get the same affect on solaris?

Comment: I don't have a Solaris machine to test on since 2008.  :)  The only part I think has any risk of not working is the `-m1` part, so if Solaris doesn't support that, just put your `head -1` back instead.

Comment: on solaris I get grep: illegal option -- m

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: that is not true.  The `-w` prevents it.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that... (`-w` isn't specified by POSIX).

Comment: John Zwinck what you think about Sriharsha Kalluru solution ?

Comment: @maihabunash: I think the Sriharsha Kalluru solution is good, if it works for your use case I think you should go with that one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getent` command to get it done instead of `grep` command.

```
[root@myserver ~]# cat /etc/hosts
5.5.5.5  GH_T  T1 T2 T3 # machine_VIP
# 198.2.3.12 MON1 MON2  machine_VIP
18.2.4.12 W1 # machine_VIP # machine_VIP # machine_VIP
192.9.200.77 machine_linux1 machine_linux2  machine_VIP
192.9.200.78 machine_linux10 machine_linux20 machine_VIP_test

[root@myserver ~]# Cluster_VIP=$(getent hosts machine_VIP |awk '{print $1}')
[root@myserver ~]# echo $Cluster_VIP
192.9.200.77
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this single `sed` statement?

```
sed -n '/^[^#]*\bmachine_VIP\b/s/[[:space:]].*//p' /etc/hosts
```

(uses GNU `\b` for word boundary—this can be easily modified to not use GNU extensions).

Or, since you're using Bash, you could use `grep` as so:

```
read -r Cluster_VIP _ < <(grep '^[^#]*[[:space:]]machine_VIP\([[:space:]]\|$\)' /etc/hosts)
```

No chain of `awk`, `tail`, `grep`, etc. needed.

Or, with a single `awk`:

```
Cluster_VIP=$(awk '/^[^#]*[[:space:]]machine_VIP([[:space:]]|$)/ {print $1;exit}' /etc/hosts)
```

---

Now, a pure Bash possibility, so that you'll be sure it'll run anywhere Bash is installed:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^[^#]*[[:space:]]machine_VIP([[:space:]]|$) ]] || continue
    read -r Cluster_VIP <<< "$line"
    break
done < /etc/hosts

if [[ $Cluster_VIP ]]; then
    echo "$Cluster_VIP"
else
    echo >&2 "Cluster VIP not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -w '^[^#]* machine_VIP' /etc/hosts | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

First grep - exact word match for machine_VIP with same case in /etc/hosts file

second grep - to ignore all the rows which contains #

Awk - to print ip address

head - to print first row for output.

Comment: This is wrong, because it will return matches where the comment character is not at the beginning of the line, but should still disqualify the line, as in some of the OP's examples.

Comment: not so good because what in case the "#" is in the last! of the line